# Laravel combine / interlace two Middlewares

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-middleware

In my Laravel project there are two types of custom middlewares:

1. Those who check if a specific user type (tutor or student) is logged in
2. Those who check the permissions of the current user

Now I need to combine these two middlewares to check for example if a tutor is logged in and also to check if the tutor has permission to enter a class.

My routes/web.php looks like this:

```php
// check tutor authentication 
Route::group('middleware' => ['auth:tutor']], function(){

    // Display routes that are enabled for all tutors like /profile

    // check if tutor has permission to enter class
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'class.permission'], function(){

       // Display class routes

    });

});
```

Unfortunately I get the following error: `Trying to get property 'headers' of non-object` 
Path: `Project/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

I would be grateful for some help.

Comment: Could you post your 2 middlewares code please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow the preconfigured auth middleware was the troublemaker. So I created a custom AuthTutor middleware and registered it in the kernel as auth.tutor to solve the problem.

Middleware code:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::guard('tutor')->check()) {
      return $next($request);
    } else {
      return redirect()->route('login.tutor');
    }
}
```

Routes Code:

```
Route::group('middleware' => ['auth.tutor']], function(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common error i have seen before, most likely you forgot to return in one of your middlewares, it needs to either return `$next` or throw an exception.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    ...

    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem yet. However I tried to create another custom middleware to replace the Middleware/Authenticate.php - and this worked out well.

Comment: show the middleware code then, it's hard to debug it without it

Comment: Thank you, but I've already come up with a better an more efficient solution - so I don't need to post the code anymore.

Comment: then atleast post the answer, and for that matter the code other people could stumble upon this question